# Missing column border due to multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, border

I have an issue with multirow. Some of the borders in my table are missing since I added one column at the end, but I can't get why. Any help is appreciated!

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccc|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Modello}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{F1-Score}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Macro F1-Score}} \\
    & 7.7 - 7.9 & 8.0 - 8.2 & 8.3 - 8.5 & 8.6 - 8.8 & 8.9 - 9.1\\
    \hline
    L. Discriminant & 0.5 & 0.56 & 0.25 & 0.4 & 0.57 & 0.46 \\
    SVM & 0.5 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0.38 \\
    KNN & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.33 & 0 & 0 & 0.25\\
    GNB & 0 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.1\\
    Decision Tree & 0.67 & 0.86 & 0.73 & 0 & 0.86 & 0.62\\
    Random Forest & 0 & 0.56 & 0.46 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.30\\
    Extra Trees & 0.29 & 0.53 & 0.62 & 0 & 0 & 0.29\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `\multirow`. Try

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

to get

[image]

The number of `&` separators should be always consistent, if you want the vertical rules to appear. You're missing one.

Can we do better? Certainly so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  range-phrase=--,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  S[table-format=1.1]
  *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
}
\toprule
Modello & \multicolumn{5}{c}{F1-Score} & {Macro F1-Score} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
& \numrange{7.7}{7.9}
& \numrange{8.0}{8.2}
& \numrange{8.3}{8.5}
& \numrange{8.6}{8.8}
& \numrange{8.9}{9.1} \\
\midrule
L. Discriminant & 0.5  & 0.56 & 0.25 & 0.4 & 0.57 & 0.46 \\
SVM             & 0.5  & 0.6  & 0    & 0   & 0.8  & 0.38 \\
KNN             & 0.4  & 0.5  & 0.33 & 0   & 0    & 0.25 \\
GNB             & 0    & 0.3  & 0.2  & 0   & 0    & 0.1  \\
Decision Tree   & 0.67 & 0.86 & 0.73 & 0   & 0.86 & 0.62 \\
Random Forest   & 0    & 0.56 & 0.46 & 0   & 0.5  & 0.30 \\
Extra Trees     & 0.29 & 0.53 & 0.62 & 0   & 0    & 0.29 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I set the `output-decimal-marker` to a comma just to show an important feature of `siunitx`. Remove the setting if you want the decimal marker to be a period.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Sorry for ditsurbing you again, could you please tell me how to make the F1 score columns only 3?

Comment: @Mauro Not sure what you mean. But if you have just three columns under “F1-Score”, you need `\cmidrule{2-4}`. The `*{3}{<spec>}` bit means “repeat `<spec>` three times”; for instance, `*{3}{l}` is equivalent to `lll`

Comment: This is exatly what I wanted to know. Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be consistent in writing ampersands in table. In the second row is mised one on the end. This two rows should be:

```
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Modello}} 
    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{F1-Score}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Macro F1-Score}} \\
    & 7.7 - 7.9 & 8.0 - 8.2 & 8.3 - 8.5 & 8.6 - 8.8 & 8.9 - 9.1 &   \\ & observe & on the end of line
```

After this correction, result of your code fragment is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't know there has to be one & at the end too